# HTTP Get API call always fails "NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found"

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created an ASP.NET Core web api which I am running locally in visual studio, I am able to browse to this in Safari and tested the API using postman.

When I use the following swift code in my MacOS app:

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/api/values")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Data is empty")
            return
        }

        let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        print(json)
    }

    task.resume()
```

It always fails with error

> NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
>   be found.

Do I have to change some settings so that my app can make Http requests to the API?

Thanks

Comment: Nope, is the swift app running locally ? Can you capture traffic with fiddler. does fiddler even see the request ?

Comment: The swift app is running locally in Xcode debugging. I’ve been able to make calls using and requests successfully using postman not used fiddler before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably already figured out a solution or a way around the problem, but since I reached the same question when having this problem I will provide my answer anyway in case anyone else finds this question.

For me the problem was that the MacOS app was not allowed to connect to the internet since it was automatically running in an app sandbox. The solution was to add "Outgoing Connections" to the app capabilities. See screenshot below.

[image]